Have anyone gotten (mono) xsp and mod_mono working on RH9 or OL9?
Have anyone gotten (mono) xsp and mod_mono working on RH9 or OL9?
I have tried with packages from 8 and 7 (with mono-project-centos8 for missing packages) without any luck.
We are aware we should migrate to dotnet core, but we need something to keep it alive until that is done.
Combinations tried:

OL9+EPEL (mono-core) + centos7 mono-project (mono-basic, xsp, mod_mono) = incompatible packages
OL9+EPEL (mono-core) + centos8 mono-project (mono-core, mono-basic, xsp, mod_mono) = segmentation fault
OL9+EPEL (mono-core) + OL8 EPEL (xsp) + centos8 mono-project (mono-basic, mod_mono) = incompatible packages (mod-mono-server2 hittas ej)

symlink mod-mono-server4 till mod-mono-server2 = segmentation fault


OL8 + OL8 Appstream + OL8 EPEL (mono-core, xsp) + centos8 mono-project (mono-basic, mod_mono) = incompatible packages
OL7 + OL7 Appstream + OL7 EPEL (mono-core, mono-basic, xsp) + centos8 mono-project (mod_mono) = incompatible packages
OL8 + OL8 Appstream + OL7 EPEL (mono-core, mono-basic, xsp) + centos8 mono-project (mod_mono) = incompatible packages


Figured out that the problem is not the packages. The problem is the configuration of selinux.
Solution is to activate httpd_execmem to allow httpd to execute programs that require memory addresses.
ex:
setsebool httpd_execmem on
see also: Mono crashes while SELinux enforced, How to get mono server worked while SELinux is enforced?
